# Congruences and probability

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Suppose that $6x \equiv 10y \pmod{14}$. Which of the following are guaranteed to be true?

(a) $3x \equiv 5y \pmod{14}$: True

(b) $6x \equiv 10y \pmod{7}$: True

(c) $3x \equiv 5y \pmod{7}$: True

(d) $6x \equiv 10y \pmod{28}$: False

Am I right?

Comment: any reasoning for reaching the conclusion?

Comment: $b,c,d$ have correct answers. You need to check if $(a)$ is written correctly, because $3x-5y$ is half of $6x-10y$, so the latter being a multiple of $14$ would not imply that half of it is a multiple of $14$,right?

Comment: Please explain your reasoning rather than simply posting proposed answers.  That might help you discover any errors you have made.  It also helps us identify any errors you may have made.  Also, please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: note that $6\cdot 7\equiv 10\cdot 0 \pmod{14}$ does not imply $3\cdot 7 \equiv 5\cdot 0 \pmod{14}$, so $a)$ is false.

Comment: Thank you for help!